# JSP: Login page to servlet to login page message passing

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

I want my this login page loaded twice i.e first time user type username and password and then get response from servlet and then it will be redirected to login jsp page with "messages".

I have two buttons for login and logout. Can this script be loaded twice by using count variable as i have tried? Any other methods will also be preferred.

Another problem: Can I have a session start only after login successfull so that i can check if user is valid or not at each page?

P.S: I have tried using `getAttribute` and `setAttribute` but they are not working.

```
if(userExists) {
    // check if password matches username or not
    if (pwd.equals(rs.getString("password"))) {
        System.out.println("Login Successful");
        message = "ValidUser";
    } else {
        message = "Invalid Password";
        System.out.println("Invalid Password from userExists");
    }
} else {
    message = "Invalid Username";
    System.out.println("Invalid Username");
}
request.getSession().setAttribute("message", message);
request.getSession().setAttribute("count", count); // count = 1;
response.sendRedirect(dest);  // dest ==> same login.jsp page
```

Login.jsp :-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var msg = <%= request.getAttribute("message") %>;
    var cnt = <%= request.getAttribute("count") %>;
    function log() {
        if (cnt != 1) {
            // document.userlogin.login.type = "submit";
            alert("Form Submitted");
            alert("count is " + cnt);
            alert("msg = " + msg);
        } else {
            document.userlogin.login.type = "button";
            if (msg == "ValidUser") {
                document.userlogin.login.disabled = true;
                document.userlogin.logout.disabled = false;
            } else if (msg == "Invalid Password") {
                alert("Invalid Password");
                document.userlogin.userpass.focus();
            } else if (msg == "Invalid Username") {
                alert("Invalid Username/ Please register and then login");
                document.userlogin.username.focus();
            } else {
                alert("msg = " + msg);
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<form name="userlogin" method="POST" action="../Login" onload="log();" >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem I can see is that in your .jsp page you are looking for the `message` and `count` attributes in the `request` object which are actually present in the `session` not in the `request`.
So change following:

```
var msg = '<%= request.getAttribute("message") %>'; // Here session needs to be checked
var cnt = '<%= request.getAttribute("count") %>';  // Here session needs to be checked
```

to get attributes from the implicit session object in the jsp.

```
var msg = '<%= session.getAttribute("message")%>';
var cnt = parseInt(<%= session.getAttribute("count")%>);
```

**another problem** : `can i have a session start only after login successfull so that i can check if user is valid or not at each page`
As soon as a user makes a request to the server a new session is created (if previous session does not exist). So there is no way of preventing a session to be created.

Also if a login is failed you can use the session for several googd things for example **You can restrict the user to maximum login attempts after several failures** by storing the number of login attempts in the session and comparing it with the `maximum login attempts allowed` before checking for login information.

Comment: he could also use the more forgiving `page.findAttribute("message")`. Also, if `message` is a String (as its name suggests), the proper syntax in the JavaScript snippet would be: `var msg = '<%=session.getAttribute("message")%>';`.

Comment: well... I just pointed out the syntax for the `msg` JavaScript variable... the other one (`cnt`) seems to be an integer (as it's just a counter) so no quotes needed for that one.

Comment: Oh, several mistakes I make. But the `findAttribute()` method is present in the `pageContext` object not in the `page` object(if I am not wrong.)